# JQuery UI: how to stop drag and drop in start

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have the following setup:

```
$('.my-list').sortable({
  handle: '.drag-handle',
  start: function(event, ui ) {

    //check to see if allow drag and drop
    var should_disable = check-code-goes-here ;
    if (should_disable) {
       //how to disable
    }

  },
  stop: function(event, ui ) {
  }
});
```

When dragging a .drag-handle element, I need to check a condition to see if it is allowed to be dragged and dropped. If yes, go as normal. If not, I would like to disable the whole drag/drop operation. Note that I cannot determine whether a .drag-handle element should be draggable or not at page load, which is why I need to check at the time of each drag/drop operation.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Check this JSFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/shuklendu/uacc7/17/

in that example a class 'fixed' added to item which don't want to drag and cancel property set to sortable by

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed"
});
```